# How to post JSON in the body of a retrofit request?

Tags: android, rest, api, retrofit2

How can I send this raw JSON into sever using Retrofit?

```
{
    "merchant": {
        "merchantUser": {
            "email":    "haaa@h.com",
            "password": "123456"

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have pojo class for your json?

Comment: @Blu Yes, I have POJO

Comment: can you show what have you tried to do with retrofit?

Comment: Solved this yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the HashMap to send json in @Body parameter for POST request

```
interface Code {
  @POST("/json")
  CodeResponse postJson(@Body HashMap<String, Object> body);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        JsonObject reqObjectParent = new JsonObject();
        JsonObject reqObject = new JsonObject();
        try {

            JsonObject reqObjectChild = new JsonObject();
            reqObjectChild.addProperty("email", "amiyobiswas001@gmail.com");
            reqObjectChild.addProperty("password", "123456");

            reqObject.add("merchantUser",reqObjectChild);
            reqObjectParent.add("merchant",reqObject);

            System.out.println("Request"+reqObjectParent);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Request will be

```
{
    "merchant": {
        "merchantUser": {
            "email":    "amiyobiswas001@gmail.com",
            "password": "123456"

        }
    }
}
```

Retrofit Post method will be

```
 @POST("YourURL")
 void YourMethodName(@Body json: JsonObject);
```